# Setting up Xdebug for drupal site

Tags: php, drupal, netbeans, drupal-modules, xdebug

I have been trying to get xdebug, netbeabs 7.0 and drupal work to no avail. The drupal site is hosted remotely on xyz.com:8081. The port forwarding is setup to forward the port 9000 to the host in that network. xdebug is installed and correctly shows up in phpinfo() but my netbeans says "waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)". Below is what I have in my php.ini

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

also I read some where that I have to have the same in my /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini and I tried that too.I tried change the localhost to xyz.com and it didn't work. 
I also need to know what should be the project configuration in netbeans. for instance xyz:8081/drupal?

Thank you all,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xdebug needs to connect back to your workstation on the port specified.  Try something like this.  The key is that the server will connect back to your workstation, so if you're behind a nat'd firewall then you need to port forward 9000 to your workstation running netbeans.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=NETBEANS_DBGP
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=IP_OF_YOUR_WORKSTATON
```

Some of these settings are described in more detail here:  http://www.flingbits.com/tutorial/view/xdebug-for-developing-debugging-and-profiling-php

There's also netbeans specific setup info here:  http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Comment: thank you very much, It worked! I totaly forgot to forward the port where my workstation resides. However I did not need to specify xdebug.remote_host=IP_OF_YOUR_WORKSTATON as I set the xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 to support workstation with an unknown IP.